# Grouping fields in Grid Layout

Tags: java, swt

I am using SWT grid layout with number of columns=2;

is there an option to add 3 elements to this layout such like:
label checkbox text

where the label is the first element and
the checkbox and the text are the second element

kind of group(with out border) of check box and text in one element in order to work with the grid layout

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i recommend using MigLayout for such things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Composite` object and use it as a parent for your checkbox and text widgets. Then you can add the `Composite` to your grid layout as a second element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer,it works fine ,but the composite is created with horizontalSpacing so big,
is there a way to put this Composite with minimum horizontalSpacing

Comment: You can customize horizontal/vertical spacing with `GridData` objects, see http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html for more details

Comment: How can i change the size of the Composite inside the grid layout